# How can I remove leiningen :injections in a profile?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I use [humane-test-output](https://github.com/pjstadig/humane-test-output) defined in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj like so:

```
{:user {:injections [(require 'pjstadig.humane-test-output)
                     (pjstadig.humane-test-output/activate!)]}}
```

However some old Clojure projects don't function well with humane-test-output active (and also sometimes I just want standard clojure.test output).

I thought I could occasionally disable humane-test-output by adding a new profile like:

```
{:user {:injections [(require 'pjstadig.humane-test-output)
                     (pjstadig.humane-test-output/activate!)]}
 :nohumane {:injections ^:replace []}}
```

So I that I can easily invoke this whenever I need to like:

```
lein with-profile nohumane test
```

However when I do this I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: leiningen.core.injected
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:77)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

Which I think is caused the by fact that I have removed [this essential injection](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/e1d27074e5d85d2bb7ae83719442e14ac4331396/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L510) that is part of lein's core and needs to be active in lein's `test` profile.

So my question is, how can I remove the humane-test-output injection in a profile but leave this core injection intact? Note, `leiningen.core.project/hooke-injection` is also private, and I have so far been unable to refer to it, even using the `#'` trick.

Comment: Would not it be easier to have `humane-test-output` in its own profile and use it when necessary?

Comment: Certainly easier, but not what I want. I want humane-test-output on all the time (it's very useful) and to be able to disable only in the cases that it can't work.

Comment: How about `lein with-profile -user test` instead?

Comment: A bit closer, definitely a good option. I'd like to have the other things in my user profile active and just disable the injections. Maybe two different profiles where the user profile activates another profile and that other profile contains the injections? Then I could disable that other profile.